# XCode update is not being reflected

Tags: xcode

I have downloaded the latest Xcode 7.2 from the App Store.

[image]

But when I open Xcode, it still show the version as 6.4.

[image]

I am running on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

How do I use Xcode version 7 and above?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I got the same problem some times ago, when, after upgrading to El Capitan, I couldn't update to Xcode 7.1.1.

To solve this issue, I did the following:

1. Remove the .app file in your Application folder (if you prefer, you can use apps like CleanMyMac to remove any other related files);
2. Go to [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) (after having logged in) and download Xcode 7.2 directly from there.

Don't know exactly why the normal update doesn't work, but now, after re-installing the app completely, everything works fine for me (also the new updates from the App store).